# How to get app version with bundle in simulator ios

Tags: terminal, version, simulator

I want to get the app version, code version in the simulator IOS in terminal.

I may get it in android simulator in command line by run this code:

`adb shell dumpsys package com.active.dev | grep version`

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but I hope that it could help, you need to :

1. Get the app container using this command :

```sh
xcrun simctl get_app_container booted bundleID
```

2. Execute this command :

```sh
defaults read **The app container**/Info CFBundleVersion
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to better format your questions with code.